# Remove commas from input box after clicking submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am wanting to know if its possible to take off commas from an input box when clicking a submit button using jQuery.

I am trying to take in a number value from users that automatically adds in commas for easier readability, ex: $1,000,000. I have gotten this running however when the user submits the data, our backend cannot read values anything else other than numbers so I am wanting to know if I can change the values with commas to just numbers when the user clicks the submit button?

Comment: can you share what you've tried?

Comment: Look into regex and `String.replace()`

Answer (score 4):

```
$('#your-form').on('submit', function() {
    var input = $('#your-input');
    input.val(input.val().replace(/,/g, ''));
});
```

Comment: This only replaces one comma

Comment: @IrkenInvader Fixed ))

Answer (score 2):

The better way do not store any chars exept numbers in such fileds. I usually use regex in such cases.

```
console.log($('#input').val().replace(/[^0-9]/g, "")); // result 1000000
```

Then you can format value on show page as you wish. Later.

---

Best regards

Egor

Comment: For decimals:
`console.log($('#input').val().replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, ""));`